# Add an apostrophe to a file name via http header - encoding

Tags: java, servlets

I would like to add an apostrophe to a file name.  The file is generated on my Java server and sent back via a Faces-based HTTPServletResponse object.  Whith the code below, the filename ends up being "french_filename.txt".  What is the correct way to encode the apostrophe to ensure that the filename is sent down correctly?

```
HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) facesContext.getExternalContext().getResponse();

response.reset(); 
response.setContentType("application/txt"); 
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"french'filename.txt\"");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work in both IE and Chrome, I found that "french\'file" worked best.

Answer (score 3):

Since the apostroph is a [reserved character](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) you probably need to encode it. Try to encode all file names using URLEncoder:

```
URLEncoder.encode("french'filename.txt", "UTF-8"));
```

It will return: `french%27filename.txt` You can choose a different encoding if you need to.

Comment: Interesting - this works in IE but Chrome leaves it as the %27.  This is the first time I've ever seen IE work better than Chrome!